# Why my text box input disappear after I get my first data?

Tags: javascript, html

1. When I get my first data via my button the text boxes aren't there any more 
   and I don't have any errors
2. After clicking in the add button with no boxes on my page the new empty lines would be added on the top of my first data which has been added to my table but it should be added under my first data

```js
function add()
{
  var fname= document.getElementById('FirstName');
  var lname= document.getElementById('LastName');
  var person = document.createElement('tr');
  var fn = document.createElement('td');
  var fnNode = document.createTextNode(fname);
  fn.appendChild(fname);
  var ln = document.createElement('td');
  var lnNode = document.createTextNode(lname);
  ln.appendChild(lname)
  person.appendChild(fn)
  person.appendChild(ln)
  document.getElementById('tbl').appendChild(person)
}
```

```html
FirstName <input type ="text" id="FirstName" /> <br />
LastName <input type ="text" id="LastName" /> <br />
<input type ="button" value = "Add" onclick="add()"/><br />
<hr />
<table id="tbl" align="center" border="1" width ="400">
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're appending the fields (`fn.appendChild(fname);` + `ln.appendChild(lname)`) instead of `fn.innerHTML = fname.value;` + `ln.innerHTML = lname.value;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
function add()
{
  document.getElementById('tbl').innerHTML+='<tr><td>'
    +document.getElementById('FirstName').value+'</td><td>'
    +document.getElementById('LastName').value+'</td></tr>';
}
```

```html
FirstName <input type ="text" id="FirstName" /> <br />
LastName <input type ="text" id="LastName" /> <br />
<input type ="button" value = "Add" onclick="add()"/><br />
<hr />
<table id="tbl" align="center" border="1" width ="400">
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

... write less, do more!

Answer (score 0):

```
I don't know why you made it so complicated we can write it two lines but anyhow I've come up with elaborate solution here you go




    function add() {
      var fname= document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
      var lname= document.getElementById('LastName').value;
      let table = document.getElementById("tbl");
      let row = table.insertRow(-1);
      let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      cell1.innerHTML = fname;
      cell2.innerHTML = lname;
 }
    FirstName <input type ="text" id="FirstName" /> <br />
    LastName <input type ="text" id="LastName" /> <br />
    <input type ="button" value = "Add" onclick="add()"/><br />
  <hr />
    <table id="tbl" align="center" border="1" width ="400">
      <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```